# Shared Hosting scheduled mail in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, email, scheduled-tasks

Hai guys,
          I want to send scheduled mail every morning from my application and my website is on shared hosting.... I am using asp.net 3.5 and mysql

Comment: This is a Dup of 1350634

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont have  much options

1. Upgrade your hosting.
2. Develop an aspx page which wil send these emails and open that page periodically from another pc.

Edit : **YOU HAVE ASKED THE SAME QUESTION SOME TIME BACK** and I myself have answered and there are other good answeres too.  Why are you reposting?

[Scheduled Mail in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350634/scheduled-mail-in-asp-net)

Comment: Don't you just hate it when that happens!

Comment: Yeah ;-) I couldnt stop shouting.