# Is it possible to send mail automatically every 3rd day from registration date from website

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I have developed a website and want to send an auto-generated mail to new user's regarding the website on every 3rd day from their registration day.

I don't know is it possible or not. If it is possible, can I know how ?

Thanks for the help..

Comment: Yes, it is possible. There are plenty of ways to achieve this.

Comment: When you say every third day, do you mean each user gets email on 3rd day, 6th day, 9th day etc or just once on 3rd day?

Comment: @Rostech Can I know the easiest or the best way to do that ?

Comment: @JonathanWillcock Yes, It's like that only. On 3rd day, 6th day, 9th day, etc..

Comment: @JayPatel this is the easiest but not the best way. [Click me](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/49996/Schedule-Email-Through-ASP-NET-or-Schedule-Tasks-U)

Comment: @JayPatel, you can also look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350634/scheduled-mail-in-asp-net)

Comment: @Rostech I am confused now. For what I should go for ? Windows Service or Application Start ? Please guide me which is the suitable one.

Comment: @JayPatel, oh, I'm sorry I've got you confused. I would go with windows service.

Comment: Windows service for once a day job is a bit overkill . For windows I suggest Task Scheduler. You can create a windowless app which is called by the scheduler rather than having a service with a long timer running all the time.

Comment: @Rostech As per your preference I done all the things and edited according to my requirement and its working great in localhost but when I upload the Global.asax file on sever my website shows runtime error. Is their any solution of this ??

Comment: @Rostech Sorry.. Its my mistake in uploading files. Auto-mail is working awesome. Thanks for all you help.

Answer (score 0):

To get every day the users who are 3,6,9 days old etc. you need to run daily a SQL statement along the lines of (this is T-SQL syntax):

```
SELECT UserName, EMail FROM Users WHERE (cast(RegistrationDate as int) - cast (GETDATE() as int)) % 3 = 0 AND RegistrationDate > GETDATE()
```

As to which method to use for your daily task, as we say in English "you pay your money and you take your choice".  However, I do not think it a good idea to have a timer on your website just to do a once a day job.  Better would be something like Task Scheduler on Windows or cron on Unix/Linux.

Answer (score 0):

**Using C#**

1. Write a console application to get the dataset of users whose registered date is meeting 3 days bucket & send email using smtp
2. Build & get .exe file to configure in Task scheduler on your required schedule

[Refer this](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSEmailScheduler-21564366)

**Using SQL**

1. Use sp_send_dbmail in SQL server to distribute email

[SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13300881/how-to-send-email-from-sql-server)